# Linux clients are not being timed-out by captive portal

Tags: wifi-hotspot

A captive portal at my local coffee shop let's all clients (both in the sense of IT and of buyer) running Linux to use the Wifi as long as they wish.

Windows clients are treated differently, and after 45' they are kicked out of the network.

What could be causing this? I discard it being a setting done on purpose. What did they do wrong?

Comment: Are the Linux users not even kicked out for a short time where it then reconnects?

Comment: @phk: that could be the case. Maybe they were kicked out and connected immediately after, not noticing it. I'll check this the next time I go there.